# Laravel Form Validation Message View

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.7

Sorry for my title.

I'm using `Laravel 5.7.*`

Right now my form validation message view is like this:
[image]

But i need it like this, i mean atleast error message appear below input fields:
[image]

Displaying Error Like This:

```js
@if(count($errors)>0)
  <ul>
  @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <li class="alert alert-danger">
      {{$error}}
    </li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
@endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply write this in your desired location.

```
{{ $errors->first('input_name') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to display errors under your form elements. You can do something like this.

```
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('description') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">Description</label>
        {!! Form::textarea('description', null,['class' => 'form-control',
        'placeholder' => 'Type Description']);    !!}
        <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('description') }}</small>
   </div>
```

Here:

```
    $error->has('description')? 'has-error' : '' ,
```

will add 'has-error' class on the form-element which will make the form-elements red lined around it.

And:

```
    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('description') }}</small>
```

will display the validation message in red under the form-element. Here, 'description' is our defined validation rules.